# Microsoft Graph API: Group Calendar Events created by API are not sent to users Calendar

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

When I create (or update) an Event in the Calendar from the Outlook Desktop Application every member of the group gets the Event in his personal calendar - (or according to the "Follow in Inbox" setting).

When I create an Event using the Graph API, the event shows up in the Groups Calendar, but it is not pushed to the Members calendars. There is also no notification in the groups inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an Event using the API, make sure to also invite the group itself as attendee.

Additionally the MS Flow (Power Automate) connector, does not allow for this.