# How to create an event in a "Group Calendar" using MS Graph API (PHP plugin)

Tags: php, events, microsoft-graph-api, nscalendar

How to create an event in a "Group Calendar" using the MS Graph APIs?
This is only possible using delegated permission from a Work or School Account.
Would you please share the code to achieve that (using the PHP - new Graph())?
Is it possible to do it completely silently, or login or consent pop-ups are involved?

[HideAndSeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4311829/hideandseek) says he did it in the post: [Microsoft Graph API: Group Calendar Events created by API are not sent to users Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298166/microsoft-graph-api-group-calendar-events-created-by-api-are-not-sent-to-users) but he does not share the code or explained how he did it.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure is [this the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that states the create event api that you intend to use?

Comment: The way to do this is using the Flow 2 - Get Access Token From Client and User Credentials, not the client_credentials flow.: https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau

Answer (score 0):

To use APIs that only support delegated permissions, authentication + user consent is required. Below is a code sample assuming the access token variable is acquired with delegated permissions. I am using [MS Graph PHP SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)

```
$accessToken = 'eyJ0...';

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$attendees = [];
array_push($attendees, [
        'emailAddress' => [
        'address' => 'user@domain.com',
        'name' => 'Name'
        ],
        'type' => 'required'
        ]);
$newEvent = [
  'subject' => 'Sample Event Subject',
  'attendees' => $attendees,
  'start' => [
    'dateTime' => '2021-05-12T22:00:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Pacific Standard Time'
  ],
  'end' => [
    'dateTime' => '2021-05-12T23:00:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Pacific Standard Time'
  ],
  'body' => [
    "contentType" => "HTML",
    "content" => "Chat about new hire"
  ]
];

$response = $graph->createRequest('POST', '/groups/group-id/calendar/events')
  ->attachBody($newEvent)
  ->setReturnType(Model\Event::class)
  ->execute();

echo "Created event - {$response->getSubject()}.";
```

Here is a [complete example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-phpapp) that will help you get started. The Guide is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php)